# HttpClient.GetAsync is getting Internal Error (500) but Chrome gets a response

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

For some reason I am getting Internal Error 500 when using c# HttpClient.  The URL doesn't respond with 500 error when using chrome/web browser or Postman.

The Test URL I am using is "https://onlinetools.ups.com/track/v1/details/asdfa"

When I access the URL directly via Chrome by pasting it in, it gets the below response

```
<CommonResponse>
    <response>
        <errors>
            <errors>
                <code>250003</code>
                <message>Invalid Access License number. Access Key not found</message>
            </errors>
        </errors>
    </response>
</CommonResponse>
```

It gets similar result for Postman (though in JSON format)

But when I try to do it via HttpClient I get an Internal 500 Error.  The Test code is

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var testResult = client .GetAsync("https://onlinetools.ups.com/track/v1/details/asdfa").Result;
        }
```

Does anyone ever seen something similar or know of a fix?  This is a bit too deep for my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same response you need to set the `Accept` header in your request, like this

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
var testResult = client.GetAsync("https://onlinetools.ups.com/track/v1/details/asdfa").Result;
Console.WriteLine(testResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

You will then receive a response in JSON as in Postman.

Consider making it asynchronous. This is just an example to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the await-Operator. Write it like this:

```
var testResult = await client.GetAsync("https://onlinetools.ups.com/track/v1/details/asdfa").result;
```

But dont forget: Your method also needs the async operator or it wont compile.

Comment: You cannot await `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: You can await `HttpResponseMessage` , like really, you can do that.

Comment: Can you show me this code running or even compiling? For example on dotnetfiddle?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IHSTbV
Copy-pasted a part of a bigger program, but it should be working.

Comment: But this is a different code. You are still not able to await `HttpResponseMessage`. Read your answer again. There is also no `result` property, but `Result`. You are awaiting the async method in your code which returns `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`